# The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded in asmx issue

Tags: web-services, asmx

I'm having the following message: `The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element` in my mvc 4 application using a web service.

The web service is a asmx file. I've tries some of the solutions mentioned in the forum
(like exending the maxReceivedMessageSize), but still I got the same error message:

My web config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />


    </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding  name="ServiceSoap"  maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>

            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://haifaws.haifanet.org.il/service.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap"
                contract="ServiceReference1.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap" />
            <endpoint address="http://haifaws.haifanet.org.il/service2.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Service2Soap"
                contract="ServiceReference2.Service2Soap" name="Service2Soap" />

        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out...

In web config of the application:

Keep on identical naming in client and binding tags

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:60971/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceClient.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```